# Formulate $P_0(\inf\{n\ge 1 : X_n=0\} \ge 2n)$ for random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, markov-chains

Consider the random walk $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ with transition probabilities
$p_{i,i-1} = q <  p = p_{i,i+1}$ with $p+q=1$ for $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ , and given $X_0 = 0$ . Define the first return time  $T_0 = \inf\{n\ge 1 : X_n=0\}$ .

Is there any way to formulate/calculate $P_0(T_0 \ge 2n)$ (or $P_0(T_0 = 2n)$) for any positive integer $n$ ?

Not sure if it's useful but I tried to formulate $P_0(X_{n} = i)$ for any state $i$ and positive integer n . Which is $0$ unless it has the form  $P_0(X_{|i|+2c} = i)$ for non negative integer $c$ .
$$
P_0(X_{|i|+2c} = i) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\binom{i+2c}{c} p^{i+c}q^c &  i>0 \\
\binom{|i|+2c}{c} q^{|i|+c}p^c &  i<0 \\
\binom{2c}{c} p^{c}q^c &  i=0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derivable from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/226578) or [p.12](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7E2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/Lecture16.pdf) :
$$
P_0(T_0=2n)=\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}
$$
$$
P_0(T_0< \infty) =   \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2i-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}} 
=  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \binom{2(i-1)}{i-1}\frac{1}{2^{2(i-1)}} - \binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}} = \binom{0}{0}\frac{1}{2^{2(0)}} = 1 
$$